# Cannot change Mariadb/Mysql sql_mode

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04, mariadb

I've got an Ubuntu server 16.04.3 installed running Mariadb and recently updated to 10.2.9-MariaDB. Since the previous update, I've now got a sql_mode looking like `sql_mode = 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,STRICT_ALL_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,TRADITIONAL,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'`, presumably the default, but I need to make some changes. Namely dropping `NO_ZERO_DATE` and potentially `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` to get an application working again.

[image: /etc/mysql/**/*.cnf]

The problem is that I've added a specific `sql_mode =` into several of the .cnf (options) files (listed in screenshot), bounced/restarted the mysql server after every change, bounced the entire server, and nothing. No change to the query `> SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode global;`.

Google is not helping - what am i missing?

Update:
I finally figured out where the default setting is coming from.
the `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` contains `sql_mode = NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,TRADITIONAL`.

And given:

```
TRADITIONAL | Makes MariaDB work like a traditional SQL server. Same as:

STRICT_TRANS_TABLES, STRICT_ALL_TABLES, NO_ZERO_IN_DATE, NO_ZERO_DATE, ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO, TRADITIONAL, NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER
```

Which tells me that the cascade of **.cnf's** IS NOT BEING READ as expected.

Comment: I don't see any "attached .cnf files". What exactly did you edit? What changes did you make? And by 'bounced" do you mean "restarted"?

Comment: ...'cause i forgot it - check now

Comment: Have you tried to change it in MySQL CLI?

Comment: @AlexanderTolkachev - I had first tried changing sql_mode in CLI +log out and back into mysql, and saw no change to the SELECT return

Answer (score 0):

Removing `TRADITIONAL` from updated **sql-mode** value solves and prevents `TRADITIONAL` from expanding into `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES, STRICT_ALL_TABLES, NO_ZERO_IN_DATE, NO_ZERO_DATE, ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO, TRADITIONAL, NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER`

Answer (score 0):

This is not answering the OP, but may answer someone else's google search when they come upon this page (as I just did):

I had trouble setting the sql-mode in `my.cnf` because there were spaces between the individual settings. In other words, this worked:

`[mysqld]
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"`

This didn't:

`[mysqld]
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES, NO_ZERO_IN_DATE, NO_ZERO_DATE, ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO, NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER, NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"`

Note: the sql-mode line is all on one line - word-wrapping on Stack-Exchange is pushing it onto a second line here.

Unfortunately MySQL workbench generated config for me with spaces - but MySQL was not telling me what the problem with `my.cnf` was.

I am running MySQL 5.7 on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: doesn't seem to work for me